# OpenGL Vertex Buffer Object

Tags: c++, opengl, opengl-3

Should I use the GL_COLOR_ARRAY to convert colors to VBO? I did use this in my code. Besides to convert vertices to VBO I used GL_ARRAY_BUFFER. The purpose is to transfer both color and vertices variables to VBO (GPU). I am confused, I did everything to run this program but

```
still gives me a segmentation fault.

    GLuint vboIds[2];
    QVector<QVector3D> vertices;
    float* colors;
```

initialization:
The length of the vertices array is (6 * ANGLE_COUNT=360 * RANGE_COUNT=100)

```
initializeGLFunctions();
// Generate 2 VBOs
glGenBuffers(2, vboIds);

// Transfer vertex data to VBO 0
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vboIds[0]);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 6 * ANGLE_COUNT * RANGE_COUNT * sizeof(QVector3D), vertices.constData(), GL_STATIC_DRAW);

// Transfer index data to VBO 1
glBindBuffer(GL_COLOR_ARRAY, vboIds[1]);
glBufferData(GL_COLOR_ARRAY, 6 * ANGLE_COUNT * RANGE_COUNT * sizeof(GLushort), colors, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
```

So far, I initialized vertices as an array buffer to the mentioned length as well as the colors buffer.

Rendering function:

```
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vboIds[0]);
glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, vboIds[1]);

int vertexLocation = shaderProgram->attributeLocation("vertex");
shaderProgram->enableAttributeArray(vertexLocation);
glVertexAttribPointer(vertexLocation, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 6 * ANGLE_COUNT * RANGE_COUNT * sizeof(vertices.constData()), (const void *)0);

int Color = shaderProgram->attributeLocation("color");
shaderProgram->enableAttributeArray(Color);
glVertexAttribPointer(Color, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 6 * ANGLE_COUNT * RANGE_COUNT *sizeof(colors), 0);

//glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 6 * ANGLE_COUNT * RANGE_COUNT, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);

glEnable    (GL_BLEND);
glBlendFunc (GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, vertices.size());
```

I do not understand why this program cannot run. Besides, when I transfer colors and vertices to VBO, imagine now I want to change the value of some indices of colors variables, how can I do that?

Comment: *Could anyone fix it please.* **NO** Please read the rules and suggestions before posting.

Comment: It is really hard to tell what you are actually trying to do. There seems to be a heavy confusion about the difference between colors and vertex indices (however such misunderstanding could arise) and it is really hard to come up with an answer other than *"consult a proper OpenGL learning resource to clear some fundamental misunderstandings"*.

Comment: could you introduce a proper OpenGL resource to me please.

Comment: see my code in the answer, I added the coded for vertices creation. Hence, what I want to do is clear.

Comment: @SamiraBayat If you got an update to your question then, well, update your question. Answers are not comments.

Answer (score 0):

You need three buffer objects. One for the vertex-coordinates, one for the vertex-indices and one for your colors. Note that the vertex-buffer must have the same length as the color-buffer. The size of the index-buffer should be divisable by three if you draw triangles. So far for the theory, now to your code:

```
// Transfer index data to VBO 1
glBindBuffer(GL_COLOR_ARRAY, vboIds[1]);
glBufferData(GL_COLOR_ARRAY, 6 * ANGLE_COUNT * RANGE_COUNT * sizeof(GLushort), colors, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

//...

glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, vboIds[1]);
```

Use `GL_ARRAY_BUFFER` instead of `GL_COLOR_ARRAY`. 
You need an extra-buffer for your colors, the index-buffer (element-array-buffer) just indexes the vertices (connects vertices to triangles so to speak).

Full example (I only know how to manage an interleaved buffer-layout atm, so I changed the data setup a bit, also I do not use an index buffer since I assume the vertices are already layed out the way triangles would be painted):

```
struct vertexData
{
    float x, y, z;
    float r, g, b;
};

//...

size_t numVerts = 6 * ANGLE_COUNT * RANGE_COUNT;
vertexData *verts = new vertexData[numVerts];

for(size_t i = 0; i < numVerts; i++)
{
    verts[i].x = vertices[i][0];
    verts[i].y = vertices[i][1];
    verts[i].z = vertices[i][2];
    //I assume you have three floats per color per vertex
    verts[i].r = colors[i*3+0];
    verts[i].g = colors[i*3+1];
    verts[i].b = colors[i*3+2];
}

GLuint vboIds[1] = {0};
glGenBuffers(1, vboIds); //only one buffer needed

// Transfer vertex data to VBO 0
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vboIds[0]);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, numVerts * sizeof(vertexData), verts, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
delete[] verts; //no longer needed


//...


glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vboIds[0]);

int vertexLocation = shaderProgram->attributeLocation("vertex");
shaderProgram->enableAttributeArray(vertexLocation);
glVertexAttribPointer(vertexLocation, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(vertexData), NULL);

int colorLocation = shaderProgram->attributeLocation("color");
shaderProgram->enableAttributeArray(Color);
glVertexAttribPointer(colorLocation, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(vertexData), (const char*)(sizeof(float)*3));

glEnable    (GL_BLEND);
glBlendFunc (GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, numVerts);
```

I hope this helps you understanding basic priciples of vertex buffers etc. Please do not copy&paste this code into your codebase but try to understand what I did here. Then rewrite your code, it's completeley messed up which shows me that you did not understand basic principles.

Comment: *"Use `GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER` instead of `GL_COLOR_ARRAY`"* - No, use `GL_ARRAY_BUFFER` instead of `GL_COLOR_ARRAY`. *"I hope this helps you understanding basic priciples of vertex buffers"* - I'm afraid it doesn't.

Comment: please see the answer above, I did not how to paste it here.

Comment: i receive error when I call glMapBuffer() function:error: 'glMapBuffer' was not declared in this scope --- I googled the error but I didn't find anything except one thread that was confusing. Does anyone know what library to add? But I think I should add a #define instead. But don't know what to add.